# Objective-C macro with weak self

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor, objective-c-blocks, self

I have a macro that performs an awesome log. However, it can't be used from within a block owned by `self` because it will form a retain cycle.

The awesome log:

`#define AWESOME_LOG(__FORMAT__, ...) ALog((@"%p %s:%d " __FORMAT__), self, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

The not so awesome retain cycle:

```
- (void)someMethod:(BOOL)awesome
{
    self.dumbBlock = ^{
        AWESOME_LOG(@"Is this awesome? %@", awesome ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    };
}
```

Is there any preprocessor voodoo that can ensure that `self` is weakly referenced here?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You always need `__weak id weakself = self;` somewhere before the block.

Comment: related: `NSAssert` contain `self` inside, use it in block also have same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using @weakify/@strongify. It creates a new weak/strong reference that shadows `self`.

http://blog.aceontech.com/post/111694918560/weakifyself-a-more-elegant-solution-to

```
- (void)someMethod:(BOOL)awesome {
    @weakify(self);
    self.dumbBlock = ^{
        @strongify(self);
        AWESOME_LOG(@"Is this awesome? %@", awesome ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    };
}
```

Comment: `@strongify` is required. otherwise you only created `self_weak_` variable.

Comment: thats [`@strongify`](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/87626584deedc9b63cf7f4c62820988ff5816567/extobjc/EXTScope.h#L83) does